# is that possible that administrator show all entry which is insert by register user in joomla?

Tags: joomla1.5

is that possible that administrator show all entry which is insert by register user in joomla?....thank you

Answer (score 2):

A general low-level approach that might be tedious but always works: look at the association of the users primary key with any other table (used as a foreign key) in the database level.